# Función jquery no funciona en IExplorer 10 y 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

mi función valida todo bien en Chrome, safari y Firefox, pero en IE 10-11 a pesar de completar correctamente todos los campos no me permite avanzar a la siguiente etapa.

```
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["form-pension"]["answer_a"].value;
    var b = document.forms["form-pension"]["answer_b"].value;
    var c = document.forms["form-pension"]["DOB1"].value;
    var d = document.forms["form-pension"]["DOB2"].value;
    var e = document.forms["form-pension"]["DOB3"].value;
    var f = document.forms["form-pension"]["z"].value;
    if (a == "" || b == "" || c == 0 || d == 0 || e == 0 || f == null) {
        $('.inrut-val').addClass("rut-error");
        $('#nom_form').addClass("rut-error");
        $('.date1').addClass("rut-error");
        $('.date2').addClass("rut-error");
        $('.date3').addClass("rut-error");
        $('.sexo-input').addClass("rut-error");
        $('.env1').attr("disabled", true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Tienes algún error en la consola? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta con mas datos, si tienes errores, coloca la descripción del error. Creo que ayudaría si colocas el código completo. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene el Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Tal vez sea por intentar acceder a la propiedad `disable` con `attr()`, en dado caso debería probar con `prop()` `$('.env1').prop( 'disabled', true );`

Comment: Considera agregar el html del formulario que estas usando, para poder hacer un ejemplo funcional y poder probarlo en IE

Answer (score 1):

Según la [definición de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/forms), el acceso mediante nombres a los elementos de un form debiera hacerse como

```
document.forms[<nombre>].elements[<nombre>].value
```

Tu código pareciera estar pidiendo las propiedades del elemento form y no de sus "hijos".

Si ya estás usando jQuery, por qué no le das ID a esos elementos y ocupas `jQuery(<form_id>).find(<input_id).val()`?